# When selecting a System Restore point, do the entries correspond to the state before or after the event?

Tags: system-restore

I'd like to roll back a recent system change I made (tip: ALWAYS back up the relevant branch before making a registry change, even if it seems trivial), and I'm reviewing my system restores to select the best one.  I see one which is labeled with a piece of software I'd rather not reinstall.

If I select this restore point, will I revert to the state *before* or *after* I installed that software?  Should I select this restore point to get back to the state immediately after the installation, or would this remove my new software?

[image: System Restore points]

Should I select #5 or #6 to rollback up to, but not through, the SQL Data Tools installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are before the action listed.

---

### Event-triggered restore points

System Restore automatically creates a restore point before the following events:

- Application installation (provided the application utilizes an
  installer that is System Restore compliant). If the application
  install causes system problems, the user can restore the system to a
  state before the installation of the application.
- AutoUpdate installation. AutoUpdate provides an easy way for users to
  download critical Windows updates. After the update is downloaded,
  the user can install the update on the system. If the user chooses to
  install the update, System Restore creates a restore point before the
  installation of the update begins.
- System restore. For example, if a user accidentally chooses the wrong
  restore point, the user can undo the restore operation by choosing a
  restore point before the system restore took place. The user can then
  choose the correct restore point.

[Windows Dev Center : Restore Points](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378910%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

When I install an update, it sets the restore point first and names it as an update or whatever-then it updates. So If the restore point says "install xyz" it is created immediately before the install. Rolling back to that will have you back to how it was before the install..

I messed up my network adapters the other night and it reset then beautifully as I had created a restore point before